# sed capture everything until pattern using variable as string

Tags: variables, awk, sed, grep, echo

I have the a bunch of text that is represented similar to xml.

```
<File>
    <abc1>
        <Hex>
            <item>
                <data>AB CD 34 43</data>
            </item>
         </Hex>
    </abc1>
</File>
```

I use an application (ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped) which takes a file as an argument and decodes it.

I can successfully run:

```
./application /tmp/file and it decodes correctly
```

I can also capture everything up to and including the line that contains the hex below (this works well, but of course, cannot enter in data everything into file and then run it - need to do it with a variable dynamically:

```
./application /tmp/file | sed '/AB CD 34 43/q'
```

But what I am unable to do is pass a variable instead of the hex string

```
./application /tmp/file | sed '/`echo -n "$value"`/q'
```

I don't mind what I use, sed/awk/grep.

My main aim is to extract everything up to the hex address then run another command to copy the same in the other direction, that I am left with mostly one complete "frame" if you will. Then I can just tail it for the frame size so it contains just one complete frame.

Comment: [You can't parse xml with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: thanks @KamilCuk I think you are right. Frustrating as I was almost there, but better to get it correct and there is probably an easier way with xmlstarlet, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./application /tmp/file | sed "/$value/q"
```

Research quoting in shell and difference between single and double quotes.

For parsing XML files use XML aware tools, like xmlstarlet. Do not parse XML with regex.

Do not use ` backticks - use `$(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your command substitution (backticks) is inside hard (single) quotes (`'`), so the shell won't expand it. You don't need `echo`, either, just the variable itself. You must still use soft (double) quotes (`"`), for the variable to be expanded.

```
hex='AB CD 34 43'

./application /tmp/file | sed "/$hex/q"
```

When using shell variables in `sed` addresses, just remember that it's a regular expression, not a string, and `sed` doesn't have an option like `grep`'s `-F` (nor would such an option help with `sed`'s `//{};` etc - the only option is to escape, beforehand). For hex it's fine, as it's only alphanumeric and space characters.

Also, as you said, `sed` will print up to the *line* containing the pattern. So any text *after* the pattern, on the same line, will be included. Perhaps this is fine for your requirements, but I'll include a few methods of printing up to (and including) the pattern exactly, but no further.

sed

```
sed -E "/$hex/{s/($hex)(.*)/\1/;q}"
```

awk

```
awk -v RS="$hex" '{print($0 RS); exit}'
```

Note: POSIX says `RS` should be a single character, but many implementations accept a regex*

shell

```
decoded=$(./application /tmp/file)
truncated=${decoded%%"$hex"*}
echo "$truncated"
```

This copies all the data to memory first, and can be slow for very large data, but fast for small data, b/c pure shell. Quoting `$hex` treats it as a string instead of a pattern.

* From https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html

> RS as a regular expression [is a gawk extension]

> mawk has allowed RS to be a regexp for decades. As of October, 2019, BWK awk also supports it.

If pattern `$hex` occurs more than once, these all print up to the first occurrence of `$hex` (including it), but can be easily modified to print to up to the last occurrence.

Finally, when doing stuff like this, remember that the `hexdump` utility can use `printf` like format strings to control output format. Eg `hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x "' mybinfile; echo` to dump a space delimited list of bytes in `mybinfile`, in hex.